# Query Request: EC2 Version

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, version-numbering, aws-sdk-java-2.0

In [StartInstances - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_StartInstances.html) Amazon describes how to make a request to Start Instances of EC2 service.

To write the parameters of request with a Signature Version 4, I followed [Common Query Parameters - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/CommonParameters.html) but I don't find the version to use.

I wonder if the version is strictly required in an `API_StartInstances` and where can I look for it? What is the last version valid for a `StartInstance` and other EC2 actions? Will there be a specific version for each EC2 command? At the moment I tried the version that I found in [Query Requests - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/it_it/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/Query-Requests.html):

```html
GET
https://ec2.amazonaws.com/?Action=StartInstances
&InstanceId.1=i-1234567890abcdef0
&Version=2016-11-15
&AUTHPARAMS
```

Comment: Side-question: Is there a particular reason you do not want to the [AWS SDK for Java](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the lastest EC2 Version that is `15-11-2016` and the list in
 https://docs.aws.amazon.com/it_it/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/DocumentHistory.html.